# Is there a way to detect missing externs?

Tags: clojurescript

The only way I know to realize that a method or property access is missing an externs declaration is by using advanced mode compilation and then testing the result very carefully. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two general rules to handle this issue. Most of the problems should be avoided by applying these rules.

1. Generate externs.js using generator solve the issues caused by external libraries
2. Use `aget`, `aset` to interact with non-clojurescript js object. Use `.-property` in clojurescript managed js object.

http://squirrel.pl/blog/2013/03/28/two-ways-to-access-properties-in-clojurescript/

Some Generators are exists.

http://michaelmclellan.me/javascript-externs-generator/

In cases, you need more information

https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/wiki/Creating-Externs

Comment: It may be noted that `aget` & `aset` are meant for arrays and that they also work for objects is an implementation detail. Preferred way to access object properties should be via `goog.object/get` and other functions in that namespace.